# How to check which program is demanding keyring access and block it?

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-keyring

Ever since I installed Chrome (because nothing else will play Netflix), i get bugged for my key ring password, *constantly*, regardless of whether i open chrome or not. (setting the password blank is not an acceptable solution here)

I see no good reason for Chrome to be doing anything whatsoever unless i tell it to - but i can see no way to stop it, or to actually check what is trying to access the keyring?

**Questions** : How can check what is currently trying to access keyring and triggering the password dialogue, and; **how** can i block it from doing so?

Google/Chrome are the only 3 things that exist inside keyrings login settings, and Skype, but i installed Skype prior to chrome and it did not trigger keyring (nor does it run on start)

Standard Ubuntu 20.04 install

Comment: someone must know how to check what programs are accessing keyring? logs show nothing and help files are unhelpful